# Correction of Translations from English to Spanish

Tags: gramática

can you please correct my mistakes?

1. My parents made me clean my room before allowing me to go out with my friends.

Mis padres me obligan a limpiar mi habitación antes de permetirme salir con mis amigos.

1. We told our friends that we would arrive late so that they would not worry.

Dijimos a nuestros amigos que llegaríamos tarde para no preocuparles.

Why is "Tarde" not "tardes"? doesn't the adjective have to agree with the plural noun amigo?

I originally translated sentence 2 with "como que" in place of "para" and wrote

"Dijimos a nuestros amigos que llegaríamos trade como que no se preocuparían.

Why is "como que" wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Revision

> My parents made me clean my room before allowing me to go out with my friends.

Mis padres me **obligaron** a limpiar mi habitación antes de dejarme salir con mis amigos.
Remember that `made` is simple past and the simple past of `obligar` is `obligaron`

> We told our friends that we would arrive late so that they would not worry.

Dijimos a nuestros amigos que llegaríamos tarde **para que no se preocuparan**.

> Why is "Tarde" not "tardes"? doesn't the adjective have to agree with the plural noun amigo?

It is tarde because tarde in this case is an adverb, and adverbs lack of gender and number.

> Why is "como que" wrong?

In this case what you have to translate is `so that`. The translation of `so that` in this case is `para que`.

Comment: what does como que mean?

Comment: @Drew _¿como qué?_ could be _like what?_. Take a look at the punctuation and the use of diacritics.

Answer (score 2):

### Revision

So so... almost correct. Let's go to check them one by one:

In the first sentence:

> My parents made me clean my room before allowing me to go out with my friends.

The translation is *almost* correct. It sounds very formal and quite artificial:

> Mis padres me *obligaron* a limpiar mi habitación antes de *permetirme* salir con mis amigos.

To me, the verb *obligar* is excesive. Sounds like a punishment. If that's the case it's alright, but if it isn't is better to say:

> Mis padres me hicieron limpiar mi habitación (cuarto) antes de permitirme salir con mis amigos.

The second verb in italics *permitir* is correct, but sounds very formal in this case, like a sentence from a textbook of Spanish... Wait!!!. At least in my country, would be more natural to say:

> Mis padres me hicieron limpiar mi cuarto antes de *dejarme* salir con mis amigos.

### Correction

Syrux is right. The correct tense in this case is `preterito perfecto simple` because the action is ended. If you say *me hacen* or *me obligan* then you mena that it happens everyday, all the time, not only once.

---

The second one is ok. But we can notice few things. The first, the tranaslation:

> Dijimos a nuestros amigos que llegaríamos tarde para no *preocuparles*.

Souns well for someone in Spain. In Mexico and maybe other places in America, that word: *preocuparles* sounds strange. Is leism, I know, but to us it sounds like missing an indirect object. We would say this:

> Dijimos a nuestros amigos que llegaríamos tarde para no *preocuparlos*.

Still better:

> Le dijimos a nuestros amigos que llegaríamos tarde para *que no se preocuparan*.

In the case of *tarde* is singular and not in plural is because it is not an adjective as you think, in this case is an adverb of time. So the use is correct in singular, always.

About you last question or doubt, `como que` isn't correct simply because is a literal translation of the English `so that`. It's more like an idiom or a way to express the same idea that in Spanish is suitable the preposition *para*.

Comment: Could you also help me with the sentence "I asked my brother to give me a ride, but he told me to walk"? I tried to translate it but I'm not literal enough.

Comment: se dice obligaron.

Comment: @syrux Thanks', you're right. I crrected the answer.

Comment: @Drew If I understand right the sentence, when you say _ride_ you mean that you ask your brother to take you in his car and somewhere near you or put you on the way. And then there is not a universal way to say it in Spanish. That concept of _ride_ in my contry (Mexico) is _aventón_ (from aventar: winnow). Then, the sentence would be translated into: _Le pedí a mi hermano que me diera un aventón, pero me dijo que caminara._

Comment: @Drew In the north of my country people also says: _Le pedí a mi hermano que me diera un ride (or raite), pero me dijo que caminara._ And also: _Le pedí a mi hermano que me diera un right [sic], pero me dijo que caminara._